# How can I get the expression of the pdf of Y for y = f(x1, ... , xN) , knowing every distribution associated to X1, ... , XN?

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability-density, sensor-fusion

Basically, the title says it all. I dispose of a function f that serves as logic to data fusion from the measures x1, ... , xN : I would like to, not using Monte Carlo or similar methods, analitically find out the pdf of Y, the random variable associated to y.
I am writing a matlab .mlx file so I dispose of the symbolic expressions of f(x1, ... , xN) and of the PDFs of the Xi associated to each xi.

Is it possible in any way, and how ?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this question is better asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unfortunately this is a problem that can't be solved in any generality. Whether or not it's possible to come up with an algebraic expression for the pdf of Y depends strongly on both the function f and the distributions of x1, ..., xN. However, there are important special cases; for example, when f = "+" and x1, ..., xN are independent, then the pdf of Y is the convolution of the pdfs of x1, ..., xN.

Comment: You might be interested in my dissertation; see https://riso.sourceforge.net/, link for dissertation is about halfway down the page. See in particular Chapter 6 about sensors and Appendix C, especially section C.3, about special cases for Y = f(x1, ..., xN).

Comment: @CrisLuengo You're absolutely right, sorry about that it has been a while since I did not visit stackExchange.

Comment: @RobertDodier Fantastic work ! I'll be reading those pages with more attention on monday.
Particularly, I asked my original question wondering how I could get the PDF of something like the mean of a winsorized dataset x1, ... , xN or the median, because you're absolutely right where the case of the mean of each sample is trivial. My final goal is to get the explicit formula for the PDF of result values using an M-estimator with huber loss, but I don't have much hope since I think that getting an explicit formula for f(x1, ... , xN) is not possible (tell me if I'm mistaken).

Comment: The most general formula for the pdf of f(x1, ..., xN) is the so-called change of variables formula, which involves the pdf's of x1 through xN and an inverse of a multivariate extension of f to N dimensions, and then integrating N - 1 times. A web search for "probability distribution change of variables" will find resources about that. So in that sense there is a general result, however, whether you can actually derive a result depends on f and the distributions of x1, ..., xN, as I was saying. What are f and x1, ..., xN? It might be possible to establish whether it's at all feasible.

Comment: In my case, each xi is a pick from a random variable following a gaussian law and each gaussian law have the same parameters so it is equivalent to picking N times from a gaussian random variable. f is determined by the merging logic of sensor fusion, and is trivial for the mean but not at all for a median value or huber's estimator. I think there are explicit formulas for fixed number of iterations for the huber estimator, i might have to dig into that.